# How do I use savefiledialog in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, savefiledialog, textedit

I have a program called TextEditPro and I just started it, I'm running into a problem.

When I had the code for clicking Save As... I don't know how to use the savefiledialog so when you click Save As it will pop up!

Any help?

Answer (score 11):

Learn to use [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) - the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) for `SaveFileDialog` has an example

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim myStream As Stream
    Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True 

    If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then 
            ' Code to write the stream goes here.
            myStream.Close()
        End If 
    End If 
End Sub
```